meaning of in the mood
What does 'in the mood" mean in this context?

6 min: Barcelona are in the mood. And when Barcelona are in the mood,
be afraid. This time Barcelona scampers in behind the Chelsea defence,
inside the area. He has to cut back, unable to shoot, and eventually
his attempted cross is deflected up for Cech to claim easily.

Barcelona vs Chelsea

It's a soccer team in the mood to pound, slam, dominate, top, rivet, take charge, have their way -- in a more-than-romantic way, with regard to the the opposing team. When Barcelona has their heart on, be afraidl

"more" than romantic? :-)

You mean it means "in a good form", doesn't it?

In the mood has wider meaning than in a good form, which is right too in this example.
Cambridge Dictionary defines the idiom be in the mood as 'to feel like doing or having something'.
For the Barcelona example, I'd add a sense of in a creative form or in an inspired form.
Barcelona are in an inspired form.
Edit
In the mood gives a sense of short durations, but good form may last longer, say, for several matches.

The other thing to note is that "mood" typically refers to a temporary or short-term state, something you might be for a single game, while "form" in sports often refers to a longer-term state, as in a whole season or year: your form is how you perform over multiple games.

Thanks, @Stuart F.  Incorporated.  I think for form a period of multiple games is reasonable.
